# Coordinates to Lat/Long Conversion

Tags: coordinate-system, openstreetmap, geojson, latitude-longitude

I'm trying to convert a GeoJSON Coordinates Point to latitude and longitude format, but I don't know exactly which is the format they have or which is the coordinate system they are expressed in.

I know this: I have a point and I know the latitude and longitude of that point. For example, `[5438568.711686796, 6354981.321006546]` should be latitude: `-32.946403` and longitude: `-60.656932`.

Comment: This looks like EPSG:5347 POSGAR 2007 / Argentina 5

Comment: Thanks! It seems you're right! 

But is there an equation for convert it to latlng? The only way I could convert it was epsg.io but I need to convert it by code.

Comment: Do you have to do this mathematically? There are lots of libraries and software out there that could reproject it for you, depending on which programming language and application you're working with.

Comment: Thank you all. I used proj4 library: https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js